# Installing software on another computer with bash

Tags: bash

I'm relatively new to all things Linux, but I've missed out on two really good job opportunities because I lack Linux experience.  To that end I've been playing around with Ubuntu and Centos on some home computers I have.
My question is this.  I have an old server box and a new desktop.  Is it possible for me to, just in bash, reach out to the server box from my desktop and install Centos on it?  I'm not really looking for instructions on how to do this now, really just after a "Yes that's possible, happy hunting!" or "That's not possible, you fool, you fly too close to the sun!"  Really I just need to know if the possibility exists so I know if my research might bring results, or if I'm wasting time.

Comment: Yes. Though I would recommend SSH/VNC (reach out) only after installation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remote install of Ubuntu Server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17450/remote-install-of-ubuntu-server) If you have any additional questions specific to CentOS, ask them at [Unix & Linux Q&A](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you both.  I will dig into that thread, karel, and see if it has what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but you're looking at different issues. Since the server, prior to installing an os, will not have a working TCP/ip stack (I.e. networking ), you won't be able to simply ssh/putty over to it.

Unless you have a device that allows you to have keyboard/video/mouse access over the network to a separate device that's then connected to the server, you won't be able to do a bare metal installation.

It is possible to configure a serial null modem connection to the server from the desk top to allow such installations (this is well documented in various older Linux how to books) most consumer grade motherboards may not support this type of connection.